# Rails multiple association types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

Can you have a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship AND a `has_many :through` relationship without any method call conflicts?

For example, what would `user.hacks` return - the hacks that the user posted, or the hacks that the user marked as favorites?

I need to be able to access both results.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hacks, through: :favorites

  has_many :hacks
end

class Hack < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hacks, through: :favorites

  belongs_to :users
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hack
end
```

Comment: what actually you are trying to do ? The associations has_many :through  which you have defined is wrong. Can you elaborate your requirement ?

Comment: @vikram What do you want to know? What do you mean by what am i actually trying to do? It's just as it says in the OP. I don't understand what is missing. Everything is there. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `has_many` defines the methods depending on the relationship name.

This means, that if you are defining a relationship several times with the same name but different options, the last definition will override the methods of the previous definition calls.

So you can't define them with the same name.

If you need to access to both, hacks and favorite hacks, you have to create the relationships as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hacks
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorited_hacks, through: :favorites, source: :hack
end
```

Comment: So how do I achieve being able to retrieve hacks in both ways? (i.e. all the hacks belonging to a user, and all the hacks that a user has favorited?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it will return, try it in the console.
However i would something like that in the user class (not tested, but you can look on how to alias relations):

```
has_many :favorite_hacks, through: :favorites, class: :hacks
```

There seems to be a typo in Hack.

On another note, the way you do it seems strange to me. The user hack relation seems like ownership, and the user - fav seems like bookmarking.

Comment: yes, your last paragraph is correct. What should be different then?

Comment: I wish to be able to retrieve all the bookmarked hacks. I also want to be able to retrive all the hacks belonging to a user.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get a list of all favourite hacks (and all hacks belong to the user), then I think it would be a much better idea to model this behaviour like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hacks
end

class Hack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :favorite, -> { where(favorite: true) }
end
```

and simply have a `favorite` attribute on your `Hack` model. Then you could find the favorites by invoking `user.hacks.favorite`.

Comment: how would you differentiate whether a hack has been favorited by a different user, if favorite is an attribute on the hack table? Favorites needs to be a separate join table.

Comment: If we take that favorites is a separate table, a scope that involves `.join` would be the version of this answer. Feel free to update the answer as such. I think people will find it useful.

Comment: My answer is only valid under the assumption that hacks (and favorite hacks) within the scope of the user.